# JS: looping counter inside the For loop is always undefined

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have a JS function to check if a file has a valid extension and return true or false to indicate file is acceptable or not.

My hidden field with value in markup:

```
<input id="hidAcceptedFormat" name="acceptedFileFormat" value="xls, xlsx, xlsb" type="hidden">
```

Here is my JS function:

```
function validateUploadedFileType(FileExtValue) {    
// Get list of accepted file format from hidden fields
var hidAcceptedFileFormat = $('#hidAcceptedFormat').val();
// Split each file format and insert into array
var acceptedFileFormatList = hidAcceptedFileFormat.split(',');    
var blnValidateResult = false;    


// Loop each file format and check if file extension is belongs to one of the acceptable format    
for (var fileTypeLoopCnt = 0; fileTypeLoopCnt < acceptedFileFormatList.length; fileTypeLoopCnt++) {
    // If file extension is indeed one of the acceptable format
    if (FileExtValue == acceptedFileFormatList[fileTypeLoopCnt]) { // Problem: fileTypeLoopCnt is always undefined
        // Verify that this file is acceptable
        blnValidateResult = true;
        // Exit current loop once verified that this file is acceptable
        break;
    }

}
return blnValidateResult;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing now is my `fileTypeLoopCnt` inside the loop is always undefined when I debug in browser.

I tried declaring a variable outside the for loop, like let's say `var ii++` and put inside the loop, and increase the counter before next loop like `ii++` but seems like whatever inside the loop will be undefined.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is `//var acceptedFileFormatList = hidAcceptedFileFormat.split(',');`  actually commented in your code ? Because that might be the problem.

Comment: sorry that I comment it out just now for testing. The actual code does not comment out and `acceptedFileFormatList` has value. Code is editted

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the line //var acceptedFileFormatList = hidAcceptedFileFormat.split(',');

Also make sure to  have id of  file format from hidden fields tag as id='hidAcceptedFormat'

Comment: Updated the code to show the value of the hidden field for `hidAcceptedFileFormat`